# Subset intraday data with chartSeries

Tags: r, subset, xts, quantmod

I want to use `chartSeries` to draw a finance plot. The x-axis needs to be in minute level. I have searched for several samples, they show that by using the `subset` argument to `chartSeries` we can plot data by date. However, I don't know how to show them in minute level. For date level, I can do something like `subset='2012-07-01::2012-07-09'`, but I don't know how to add minute level format there. Anyone has some samples?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with shiny, does it?

Answer (score 2):

From 9 a.m. on the 1st through 3 p.m. on the 9th

```
"2012-07-01 9:00/2012-07-09 15:00"
```

10 a.m. to 1 p.m. for all days

```
"T10:00/T13:00"
```